# Can I change the camera to spin on axis to turn instead of rotate around an object?

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

I've been working on a game where I make all my assets in blender and transfer them to unreal engine. I've come to prefer the unreal engine viewport navigation and was wondering if there is a way to get blenders viewport navigation as close as possible. All too often in blender I would hit the maximum zoom and be shifting my rotation point around until I could get a better view. Basically I find that I'm spending as much time correcting my viewport as I do actually building the asset. I would like to have an infinite zoom and the viewport to rotate as though it's just turning in place like it does in unreal engine. Is this possible? (I think it's similar to the "walk" or "fly" navigation but I want it at all times when building)

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an easy way to replicate this. Especially because WASD keys are used for different operators. But Walk mode on tilda (`) key works perfectly

Comment: I dont mean to use wasd keys to move, I just meant similar to the walk or fly navigation. I'd like it to be the exact same as UE4 if i could. in their editor the scroll wheel will move forward and back at a consistent speed forever whereas in blender it will slow and eventually stop when you reach the center of your pivot point. and when you click and hold the scroll wheel it will move the camera up/down/left/right just like blender when you hold the shift key while doing it. and finally (and most important to my needs) when you hold the right mouse button the camera will turn in place.

Answer (score 0):

Blender keymap is fully customizable, so you can set up a navigation in Unity/Unreal style (camera rotates in place, not around objects) if you want.

You can use Walk/Fly navigation, but assign it to the middle mouse button, so that it will enable on mouse press and disable on release. And you will be able to use WASD keys for moving camera and other keys are available also, while you're holding middle mouse button.

This guide uses the default keymap settings. If you are using Industry compatible keymap, some settings may look differently.

### 1. Setting up the rotate in place using Walk/Fly navigation.

First, I personally recommend Walk with disabled gravity.

[image]

Then in keymap open up 3D View ⇾ 3D View Global section and turn off default navigation by middle mouse (Rotate or pan depends on your settings), then set up View Navigation (Walk/Fly) to middle mouse press:

[image]

Then you should leave View Navigation on mouse release, right? So scroll down 3D View section until you find View3D Walk Modal. Disable Teleport because it  will override middle mouse action. Then add new - select action Mouse, type Confirm, Middle, Release.

[image]

Once you get it done, you will be able to rotate camera in place and navigate using WASD while holding middle mouse button.

### 2. Setting Shift+middle mouse button to pan view.

This is easy. Find Pan View in the 3D View ⇾ 3D View Global section and set it like this. Shift must be enabled:

[image]

### 3. Setting up the dolly zoom.

Once you get this, you might find that Blender still zooms at a certain point. So to avoid this, let's set up a dolly zoom instead of the default one. Again, 3D View ⇾ 3D View Global section.

Find Zoom View with Wheel In and Wheel Out shortcuts and replace text `view3d.zoom` by `view3d.dolly`. You will see that the title will change from "Zoom View" to "Dolly View". Don't forget to return Delta values, which is reset when command changes.

[image]

On my screenshot, zoom might be inverted. If you feel so too, try to replace "1" and "-1"

### 4. Get back the rotate around on a different hotkey

So this is up to you. You can get back the rotate around if you want. Just enable disabled "Rotate View" and set hotkey on Alt+Right mouse button, for example:

[image]